# Let $R$ a commutative ring and $I$ and ideal of $R$,how i can show that if $\sqrt{I}=R$ then $I=R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is trivial show that $I \subseteq R$, but i'm stuck proving that $R\subseteq I$.

If i take a $x\in R \implies x\in \sqrt{I} \implies \exists n \in \mathbb{N}; x^n\in I$

But, how i can show that $x \in I$ ?

Comment: Does a "ring" for you have to have an identity?

Comment: @Randall the exercise dont say if $R$ have identity.

Comment: Ah, okay, because then it would be trivial.  Make sure your book (or instructor) doesn't *define* a ring this way.

Comment: @Randall why is trivial?

Comment: Because you would have $1 \in \sqrt{I}$ but $1^n=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the ring $N$ of upper triangular (nilptent) matrices $M(2,\mathbb{R})$ with $0$ at the diagonal. for every element of $M$ of $N$, $M^2=0$, so $\sqrt 0=N$, but $0$ is not $N$.

Comment: Wow, slick counterexample.

Comment: @Randall If only it were commutative, as the question specified!

Comment: (In response to the edited construction) or, instead of insisting on using matrices, we can describe it more simply as "$\mathbb R$ with trivial multiplication."

Answer (score 4):

**Assuming your rings must have a multiplicative identity...**

Then your assumptions give that $1 \in R = \sqrt{I}$. Hence $1^n \in I$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. But $1^n=1 \in I$, so $I=R$ by the usual argument.

**If your rings need not have identity** then it is false by (a) rschwieb's clever counterexample or (b) Tsemo's if you strengthen the problem not to require commutativity (in both examples the rings conveniently did not have an identity).

rschwieb advocates $R=2\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ as a good **commutative** counterexample.  This is clearly commutative, but the cube of every element is $0$.  An element takes the form $2x+8\mathbb{Z}$, and the cube is
$$
\left(2x+8\mathbb{Z}\right)^3=(2x)^3 + 8\mathbb{Z} = 8x^3 +8\mathbb{Z}=0+8\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Hence the ideal $I=\{0\}$ gives a counterexample to your original statement since its radical is $R=2\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ but $I$ is not.

We should be able to give away rep points for assists...

Comment: Tsemo's counterexample isn't commutative as requested in the title, but it is trivial to construct commutative nil rings, so it is actually overcomplicated.  $2\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$ is slicker.  You should include that, and then I think your answer is most complete.

Comment: Oh wow, good catch.  Totally missed that.